# How to apply varnish of a different color on a varnished wood shed?

Tags: wood, varnishing

We have a wood shed that's only 1 year old or so. After the wood shed was assembled, we applied a varnish called mahogany. That day, I was at work. When I came home, the varnish has already been applied all over.

Over the past year, I have realized the varnish color is NOT what I would have liked. The color is orange.

How easy is it to apply a varnish of a different color?

My ideal color would be walnut (after visiting my hardware supply store). If I apply this walnut on top of mahogany, would it be a mixed color of the two? Or would it *replace* (cover up) the mahogany?

If it would be a mixed color, then how do I get rid of the mahogany?

I do also wonder if over time the orange mahogany will become more pale due 
to exposure to the sun and rain.

Does the shed need a varnish a few years down the road? If so, I can deal with this problem then.

Thank you!

Comment: could you give the name of the product used?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the varnish that got used, or more specifically depending upon that varnish's UV resistance, it may darken (yellow) soon from exposure to the sun. If it was a spar varnish, it'll withstand UV much longer. Either way, count on revarnishing after several years (less if non-spar varnish, more if spar varnish).

Walnut-stain varnish over mahogany-stain varnish will in fact result in a blended color, although the darker walnut-stain varnish will probably strongly predominate. You might try getting a tiny half-pint can of the color you'd like and run a test on a piece of scrap wood - varnish the scrap with the mahogany, let it set up fully, then varnish over in a small area with the walnut. If you still don't like the color, try another half-pint of a different color like "ebony", for example, or a blend, until you **do** like the color. When you decide what you definitely like, write a note describing what worked well and staple it to the inside wall of the shed where you'll remember it when it's time to varnish again.